# I am unable to add a product to cart in magento 2

Tags: simple-product, magento2.4.5p1, ajaxaddtocart

I have upgraded my website from magento 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1

when i am trying to add a simple product throws both of the following errors
[image]

Please help